# List of countries visited on DS-160

Tags: visas, usa, canada, international-travel, tourist-visas

When applying for a B1/B2 US visa one needs to fill out a DS-160 form. At some point this form asks "Have you traveled to any countries/regions within the last five years?". Presently, I am an international student in Canada and I am applying for a US visa from Canada. I forgot to mention Canada itself in this list of countries. What should I do now?

Comment: Mention it at the interview although I think it is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently in a similar situation while applying for a US visa. If you have indicated that you are a student and included your university's address in your application (there is a section that asks you this specifically), it is clear that you are a resident in Canada. In addition, the fact that you are applying for the visa from Canada makes it even clearer that you are inside Canada, which does not necessitate you mentioning Canada in the list of countries visited.